# Cosine Similarity Function Using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have been briefed with the below.

I have to write a function that takes in a vector x and a list of vectors and finds,
in the list, the index of the vector that is most similar to x using cosine similarity.

I have tried using the below with no luck thus far. I am very new to this so assistance and explanation would be appreciated!!

```
import numpy as np
def most_similar(x, v_list):
    dot_product = np.dot(x, v_list)
    norm_a = np.linalg.norm(x)
    norm_b = np.linalg.norm(v_list)
    return dot_product / (norm_a * norm_b)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be more efficient to use `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity` with `np.argmax` (but I did not make any benchmarks), I came up with a slight change in your code:

```
def most_similar(x, M):
    dot_product = np.dot(x, M.T)
    norm_a = np.linalg.norm(x)
    norm_b = np.linalg.norm(M,axis=1)
    score = dot_product / (norm_a * norm_b)
    return np.argmax(score)
```

You would probably need to iterate over a list, but here the argument `M` is a numpy array (each row is your vector, the elements of `v_list`), which you could easily have with `np.array(v_list)`.

Comment: Thank you. Another stupid question but attempted running with the below and receive an error. I am likely not iterating over my list of elements using what you have written.       x = np.array([1, 1])
        
M= [np.array([1. , 0.9]), np.array([-1,  1]),np.array([-6,  4])] How would I modify in order to iterate over my elemements?

Comment: Use `M = np.array(M)` and try again, should return `0` for this example.